# Окончание в слове "весело"

Tags: грамматика, морфология

В каком (каких) из приведенных предложений *-о* в слове *весело* является окончанием? Почему?

1. Всё было весело и непринужденно.
2. Он танцевал весело и непринужденно.
3. Танцевать было весело.
4. Это было весело.

Comment: По-моему, в первом. *(Это задание из олимпиады.)*

Comment: Всё было весело=всё было (делом )весёлым; танцевать было весело=танцевать было делом весёлым; это было весело= это было (делом) весёлым. Только в предл.2 нельзя заменить полной формой - танцевал как?-это наречие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, **здесь только наречия** (без окончания).

Есть такая проверка: заменить краткое прилагательное полным, но в этих предложениях этого сделать нельзя.

**Дополнение (почему О является окончанием в № 1, 2, 3)**

В № 1, 2, 3 можно задать вопрос **КАКОВО**, но нельзя задать вопрос **КАК**. Если взять пример "Он был навеселе", там тоже задается вопрос КАКОВ, но при этом при изменении рода и числа **слово "навеселе" не меняется**: они были навеселе, она была навеселе, значит, это **наречие.**

**Сравнить:** он был весел, они были веселы, это было весело, всё было весело.

Comment: В ответе целых три варианта... Интересно, как все-таки прийти к ним?

Comment: Исключить  №2, там точно наречие. Наверное, здесь формальный подход: подлежащее в форме ср.рода (всё, это)  - значит,  краткое прилагательное.  Кстати,  в Сети есть такая информация: если подлежащее – инфинитив, существительное женского, мужского рода, существительное во множественном числе, то именная часть сказуемого – наречие, но насколько это верно, трудно сказать.. http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html

Comment: Да, точно: 1, 3, 4. Как вы думаете, уместны ли подобные задания в олимпиадах?

Comment: В олимпиадах всегда нестандартные задания,  но  это мне кажется сложным. Известно, что именная часть сказуемого может выражаться наречием, например: сосед был навеселе. А если подлежащее выражено инфинитивом, почему  именная часть - это краткое прилагательное? И еще  интересно: ударения у наречия и краткой формы всегда совпадают, а то можно было бы проверить.